# What are the child objects of QGraphicsView in PyQt? How do I capture MouseMove events on top of QGraphicsView/Scene with an event filter?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, eventfilter

Alright, so. I'm fiddling around with PyQt and I'm trying to write an application where I can draw figures into a graphics scene with the mouse based on tools from a toolbar.

The way in which I capture events might be a bit strange/not the "right" way to do it, but it seems to be working for most events.

I have a container class for tool methods, which get called by actions on a toolbar. Upon entry to a method, I install the container object as an event filter on the QGraphicsView widget (I've also tried adding it to the scene instead). I'm also storing state to denote the stage of drawing I'm in. First, after clicking on the tool, I'm in a state catching mouse presses. Then, I'm trying to catch mouse movement (a line gets drawn as the user click+drags, gets finalized upon release) and then mouse release.

Events that end up being caught by the filter are mouse presses and releases, even though I'm definitely waiting for QtCore.QEvent.Mousemove (#5) -- the one that gets triggered as I move my mouse on the gfxview area.

I know that mouse movement (type 5) events are being generated, as I tried attaching the event filter to the QApplication as well. It reports the events originating from a source that isn't either one of the ones I'm attaching event filters to (so it can't get caught). If I check said source's parent, it answers back that its parent is the QGraphicsView widget.

If I then ask for the children of QGraphicsView, it lists my Graphics Scene along with three unnamed QWidgets.

Here's a debug printout from the event filter:

```
Event type: 5 
Source: 
<PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x000000000303A5E8>

Source's parent: 
<__main__.Easel object at 0x000000000303A1F8>

Easel:
<__main__.Easel object at 0x000000000303A1F8>

Easel's children: [
<PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x000000000303A708>, 
<PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x000000000303A798>, 
<PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget object at 0x000000000303A5E8>, 
<PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsScene object at 0x000000000303A288>, 
<__main__.Canvas object at 0x000000000303A558>]
```

Easel is what I'm calling my graphics view (inherits QGraphicsView) and Canvas is a re-implementation of the QGraphicsScene.

So, to re-iterate, I'd like to know what these three widgets are, if I could just slap event filters on them instead (for loop through Easel's children, add filter to each) or if there's an easier way to do this.

I'd prefer not to have to implement the mouseEvent type methods inside the Easel and Canvas classes, as I'd like to have the tool logic in one place under this aggregating class. I'm not sure if it would even help, but similar projects I've seen presented as examples in tutorials and such seem to do something like that.

I can edit the relevant methods into this post if I must, but they're really ugly and such.

Comment: You can "slap" event filters on anything you want. You don't have to ask us permission. Try it and see what happens! Your architecture is a bit off, though, since there can be multiple views of a given scene, and presumably your logic should work on any of them. The logic should work on the scene instead, I'd think.

Comment: I was just wondering if those QWidgets were obscured on purpose and capturing events on them might break something etc. but I'll definitely try it next. I kind of intend to have a single view and then just setScene() to switch to different drawings and transform the existing view if I need a different area shown or something. Not sure if it'll result in the kind of multiple views issues you mention